# Using time as X axis for Chart.js

Tags: javascript, django-templates, chart.js

I am using Chart.js to render a line chart that works well when I feed it two lists of integers for the x and y.

However, I want to use dates for the x-axis, and the documentation is a little too technical for me. Any help is appreciated!

This is what I have so far. Like I said this works well when I substitute {{times}} with a list of straight integers.

The {{times}} variable when printed is a list of dates:

```
['2018-10-21 12:21:05', '2018-10-21 12:21:05', '2018-10-21 12:21:05',
 '2018-10-21 12:21:05', '2018-10-21 12:21:05', '2018-10-21 12:21:05',
 '2018-10-21 12:21:05', '2018-10-21 12:21:05', '2018-10-21 12:21:06',
 '2018-10-21 12:21:06', '2018-10-21 12:21:06']
```

The {{recoaters}} variable is a list of integers.

My template.html running the Chart.js script:

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% block head %}
<title>Main Values</title>
{% endblock %}

{% block body %}
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.7.2/Chart.min.js"> 
</script>
<div class ="container">
<canvas id="myChart"></canvas>
</div>

<script>
let recoat_data = {{recoaters}} //y-axis
let recoat_time = {{times}} //x-axis
let myChart = document.getElementById('myChart').getContext('2d');
let valuesChart = new Chart(myChart, {
type: 'line', //bar, horizontalBar, pie, line, doughnut, radar, polarArea
data:{
  labels:recoat_time,
  datasets: [{
    label: 'Recoater Values',
    data:recoat_data,
    fill: true,
    borderColor: "#00f777",
    //borderDash: [5, 5],
    backgroundColor: "#d3fcff",
    pointBackgroundColor: "#55bae7",
    pointBorderColor: "#55bae7",
    pointHoverBackgroundColor: "#55bae7",
    pointHoverBorderColor: "#55bae7",
  }]
},
options: {
  scales: {
      xAxes: [{
           ticks: {
              display: true //removes x axis labels
          }
      }]
  }
}
});
</script>
{% endblock %}
```

It is also potentially worth mentioning this is a Django powered template.

Lastly, my thought as a last resort was to convert the dates to unix, then somehow display the labels in human readable dates. Not sure if this is possible either.

Comment: I have no knowledge about Django template, however, in chart.js there is no restriction to supply any value in the x-axis, see this jsfiddle where I have created a line chart using the values supplied by you -> http://jsfiddle.net/m5rq6bdj/

Comment: Thanks@KunalKhivensara. This seems to get me what I need.